# Can you have an instance of a class inside that class?

Tags: java, oop

In a game I am writing, I want the code to be able to figure out the best possible sequence of moves. So the logic is stored in `class Game`, is it possible to have a method `generateMoves` which creates a copy of the game to work with?

```java
class Foo {
    private String text;

    public Foo(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String doStuff() {
        Foo virtualFoo = new Foo("Can I do this?");
        return virtualFoo.text;
    }
}
```

Edit: I now know that this works, but is it bad convention?

Comment: I mean, you can try and compile that and check by yourself. Or are you asking whether it's a good idea to begin with?

Comment: What happens when you try this? Does it compile? Run? Behave as expected?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca both. If it does work is it a bad idea?

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: can you not just use 'this'?

Comment: @MatthewHaywood I basically want a virtual this to edit the game safely

Comment: It's fine if you have a use case that it actually makes sense for.

Comment: just don't do this (unconditionally) in constructor (or to initialize a filed) - that would be kind of an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine. I usually do this when testing a new class. But in the end you might want to think of the bigger picture with another class that contains and instance of all the other classes you made.